# PromptStatusで[Enter]キー、右クリックを取得する方法

Tags: .net, vb.net, ijcad, arx

IJCAD2016／VB.netで開発している者です。
IJCADのCOPY、MOVEコマンド同様にドロージグを使用したコマンドを開発しているのですが、Drag（PromptStatus）で[Enter]キーおよび、右クリックでコマンドを終了させる方法がわからず調べています。
ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら何かアドバイスをいただければ幸いです。

以下はサンプルコードおよび参照元のULRです。

```
Public Sub SampleCommand()
    Dim icDoc As Document = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument
    Dim icEd = icDoc.Editor

    '移動させるオブジェクトを選択
    Dim icSelectRes As PromptSelectionResult = icEd.GetSelection()
    If icSelectRes.Status <> PromptStatus.OK Then Return

    '移動の基点を指定
    Dim icPointRes As PromptPointResult = icEd.GetPoint(vbCrLf + "基点を指定")
    If icPointRes.Status <> PromptStatus.OK Then Return

    Using icTrans As Transaction = icDoc.TransactionManager.StartTransaction()
        Dim icMoveJig As MoveEntityJig = New MoveEntityJig(icPointRes.Value)
        For Each icSelObj As SelectedObject In icSelectRes.Value
            icMoveJig.AddEntity(icTrans.GetObject( _
            icSelObj.ObjectId, OpenMode.ForWrite))
        Next

        If icEd.Drag(icMoveJig).Status = PromptStatus.OK Then
            icMoveJig.TransformEntities()
            icTrans.Commit()
        Else
            icTrans.Abort()
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

サンプル参照元：
[.NET - DrawJigを使用してオブジェクトを移動させる - IJCAD ヘルプセンター](https://support.ijcad.jp/hc/ja/articles/206108942--NET-DrawJig%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%82%AA%E3%83%96%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E7%A7%BB%E5%8B%95%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

サンプルで参照されているソースに下記のコードを追加することで取れるようです。

■Sampler関数

```
　Protected Overrides Function Sampler(prompts As JigPrompts) As SamplerStatus
　　Dim jigPointOpt As JigPromptPointOptions = New JigPromptPointOptions(vbCrLf + "移動先を指定")
　　jigPointOpt.UseBasePoint = True
　　jigPointOpt.BasePoint = BasePoint
　　jigPointOpt.Cursor = CursorType.RubberBand
　　
　　'下記を追加
　　jigPointOpt.UserInputControls = UserInputControls.NullResponseAccepted
```

結果としてPromptStatus.Noneが戻ります。
現行のコードではキャンセルと同じ扱いとされるので、必要であればIF文で分岐すればよいと思います。